# jQuery datepicker's year dropdown pops open and closed in IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, html-select

I'm seeing an issue in IE8 with the Year dropdown in a jQuery datepicker dialog.  The dropdown opens when I click on it but only stays open until I release the mouse button.  I've only verified it in IE8 and IE9 with compatibility mode enabled, and it happens about 50% of the time I open it.  There's a button nearby that seems to gain/lose focus at the same time as the dropdown list has this problem once in a while.

Google did not offer any help.  What is happening here, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6198) concerned with the year and month dropdowns was reported months ago but is still not fixed. It sounds similar to a question [I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816511/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-issue-when-using-year-month-dropdowns/5818002#5818002) a few months ago. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it's my issue.  I'll just wait and hope it's fixed in 1.9; if not, I guess we can live with it.

Comment: I hope it is fixed in 1.9 also, but in the meantime you could make the edit yourself if it becomes a problem for users :-)